# Remove .append onmouseout jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, mouseover, mouseout

I am trying to add a 'read more' text when someone mouseovers my blog post's title.
I tried using 
`$(".blogpost").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).append(" - read more...");
  });`
But i don't know how to remove the read more... when onmouseout.

Comment: use, .show() on mouseover and .hide() on mouseout, on page load make all the read more hidden. This method is better, as you are fetching it when the page is loading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add read more in span and remove that span on mouse out

Add read more wrapped in span.

```
$(".blogpost").mouseover(function(){ $(this).append("<span id="read" - read more..."></span>); });
```

Remove added span with its id which is read in this case.

```
$(".blogpost").mouseout(function(){ $('#read').remove(); });
```

Comment: Exactly what i've been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to do this is just have the extra text in the HTML already and use a CSS :hover property to hide and show the text.  Using javascript for this adds an unnecessary level of complexity and brittleness.

Comment: This is the *correct* way, IMHO. There's no point in doing unnecessary DOM manipulation or requiring scripting for this.

Comment: I would add, that when using screen readers or clients without javascript this solution would still work, since the "read more" link would exist since the beggining.

Comment: Why haven't I thought of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
$(".blogpost").mouseout(function(){ 
    $(this).html("");
});
```

Assuming you have no child elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in javascript, You can do something like this :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a3jzF/

```
$(".blogpost").mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).append("<div class='readmore'> - read more...</div>"); 
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.readmore').remove();        
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only show and hide it once it's created. .hover() takes two functions.

```
$(".blogpost").hover(function(){
  var $span = $(this).find('.more');

  if ( $span.length ) {
     $span.show();
  } else {
    $(this).append('<span class="more"> - read more...</span>');
  }

}, function(){
  var $span = $(this).find('.more');
  $span.hide();
});
```

Or use css only (this is better):

```
<div class="blostpost">
 ...
 <span class="more">read more</span>
</div>

.blogpost .more { display: none; }
.blogpost:hover .more { display: block; }
```